# Trouble with PCB drawing

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am trying to put my remote controlled car circuit on a PCB board with minimal soldering points as I am terrible at soldering and have broken many Arduinos when trying to solder header pins.

My goal is to build a circuit board that has an IR receiver, a modelled Arduino and a motor driver all on the same board so I only have to solder the PCB to the power and the motors. I am very new to PCB printing and currently am using EasyEda and am very confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utBQqcuOt9U

Comment: What are you confused about? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am mostly confused about the drawing. I have seen many different types of Arduino in the library and how are they different. Also when I export the Arduino, will it be the Arduino circuit or is it just the drawing.

Comment: You should edit your question to show what you are actually asking. As always, the best thing to do is to start the PCB layout by placing the components. Print a 1:1 hardcopy of the layout and place your actual components on the paper. Do they line up?

Comment: Sincere apologies if I'm wrong, but I have a feeling you _might_ be imagining that the Arduino itself will be printed. PCBs contain only the connections, you still need to solder on all the parts (though there are fab houses that will do that for you).

Comment: It would be a lot easier (and cheaper) to shop for already-assembled Arduinos and IR / motor boards that don't need soldering (using terminal blocks or some cable & connector system).

Answer (score 0):

The question seems pretty vague. But since you have said any help would do, I will try to provide some tips which I generally use.

1. If you suck at soldering , never try to solder ICs or microcontrollers directly. You might burn those components. Instead connectors can be used. Search about 'arduino Shields', they are an attachment and will fit perfectly. Since arduino will have lots of pin , soldering with such high precision is hard.
2. I guess you will not require complex processing so any microcontroller is fine. Since you said arduino , three common variants are nano, uno and mega. While building the car, if size is a major constrain then go with nano.
3. Do some research on ESP32 , it have built in Wifi module. Maybe you can control your car with your phone too!
4. Anyway will making PCB, dont overheat any component. Also leave adequate space between each wire in the PCB . There are few more adhoc techniques we generally use. Just google more about those rules, they are pretty straight forward.